# How to add input file when creating jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

For my Java application, I use some input files inside **src** folder. But after I create the jar file and use it, it gives an error saying **cannot find the file**.
How to add an input file when creating jar file in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`getResourceAsStream(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), to get a stream to the file:

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("fileName");
```

This will return an input stream to the file `fileName` which is located inside a directory that `MyClass.class` is in.